# Generation of 'n' random symmetric matrices

Tags: matrix, random

I want to generate 3 random symmetric matrices, each of dimension 3 whose elements are normally distributed. It could be done simply as

```
A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {3, 3}]
B = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {3, 3}]
C = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {3, 3}]
R1 =(A + Transpose[A])/2
R2 =(B + Transpose[B])/2
R3 =(C + Transpose[C])/2
```

I am looking for other ways in which the same problem can be done for the case where number of matrices is large.

Comment: If you have a recent version of Mathematica, there are a lot of built-in distributions for random matrices. See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixDistributions.html for more.

Comment: I can't see any problem with what you are doing - do you want a simple function that generates a random matrix?

Comment: @mikado I want to generate 1000 random symmetric matrices for which using this code isn't a good idea. I am looking for better algorithm or a function to do so.

Comment: @NerdySnail Do you want just a few matrices (so you can hand pick the names) or a whole slew of them?

Comment: Let's say we have 100 of them. Handpicking would be absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your method does not work. The diagonal elements are $\mathcal{N}(0, 1),$ the off-diagonal elements are $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}).$ Secondly, `GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[\[Sigma],n]` does work (in your case, $\sigma = 1, n=3.$

**EDIT** as pointed out by Mikey, the mathematica command does the wrong thing. However, this does:

```
randomSymMat = 
  Module[{mat = RandomVariate[#, {#2, #2}], upper, diag}, 
    upper = UpperTriangularize[mat, 1]; 
    diag = DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal@mat]; 
    diag + upper + Transpose[upper]] &;
```

so

```
randomSymMat[NormalDistribution[0, 1], #]& /@ Array[3&, 1000]
```

Will do what you need.

Comment: hmmm...reading the docs, `GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[]` is a distribution of a symmetric matrix (x+x^T)/2, where x is a square matrix with independent identically distributed matrix elements that follow NormalDistribution[0,\[Sigma]]. Sure sounds like x is distributed same as A in his question, no?

Comment: @Igor,Indeed.As Pillsy already mentions,I should have used MatrixDistributions. However doing that too,doesn't lead us closer to the actual problem of generating a thousand of such matrices in a go.

Comment: @MikeY That is NOT the Gaussian Orthogonal Matrix Distribution, so either the name is wrong or the docs are wrong.

Comment: @MikeY The docs are NOT wrong. This is really messed up.

Comment: @IgorRivin You can report the problem at the `Give Feedback` link here:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution.html

Comment: @IgorRivin Thanks. I have a query. What I did in question produces 3 symmetric matrices each of which is labelled and hence can be called individually for specific operation. Could that be possible with the code you have written?

Comment: @NerdySnail Do you have a small set of "names", or a bug array of matrices?

Comment: @IgorRivin Small set of names would work. e.g Suppose I want to generate 9 random matrices. I want to multiply any 3 of them with Pauli Matix[1], another set of three with Pauli Matrix[2] and remaining with Pauli Matrix[3]. In this case, labeling generated matrices is important. While looping might be one way to accomplish this, What else could be done?

Comment: for small numbers, something like `{aa, bb, cc} = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}` works fine. For large numbers, generating a list-full of them, and either referring to them as `L[[i]]` or defining a function `rm[i_]:= L[[i]]` will work fine.

Comment: @IgorRivin Thank you

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's my shot at it.

```
makeMat[eps_, n_] := (res = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, eps], {n, n}];
                     UpperTriangularize[res] + Transpose@UpperTriangularize[res, 1])

makeMat[1,3]
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.733676 & 0.0102509 & -0.35534 \\
 0.0102509 & -0.462317 & -0.132434 \\
 -0.35534 & -0.132434 & 0.89037 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$